# Crystal - Pass instance variable to parent class

Tags: oop, inheritance, constructor, crystal-lang

I have a Crystal code with inheritance.

- The `Person` is my parent class and it has a `person_name` string parameter in the `initialize` method.
- The `Employee` is the child class and it is inherited from `Person`, it has 2 input parameters: `name` and `company_name`.

Here is a working code which **doesn't contains the inheritance**:

```
class Person
  def initialize(@person_name : String)
  end
  def greet_person()
    puts "Hi, #{@person_name} person"
  end
  def something()
    puts "It is something"
  end
end

class Employee
  def initialize(@name : String, @company_name : String)
  end
  def greet_employee()
    puts "Hi, #{@name} in #{@company_name} company"
  end
end

bob = Person.new "Bob"
bob.greet_person
bob.something

john = Employee.new "John", "Acme"
john.greet_employee
```

**Output:**

```
Hi, Bob person
It is something
Hi, John in Acme company
```

If I implement the inheritance:

```
class Employee < Person
```

I get the following error:

```
Showing last frame. Use --error-trace for full trace.

error in line 13
Error: this 'initialize' doesn't initialize instance variable '@person_name' of Person, with Employee < Person, rendering it nilable
```

Of course if I change the `person_name` to `name`, the code works (I don't want to this).

- What happen if the variable names are not the same in the parent/child class?
- How can I pass the value of `name` variable to `person_name`?

Note:

- I am using 0.36.1 Crystal version

For example the similar solution in Python:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, person_name):
        self.person_name = person_name
    def greet_person(self):
        print("Hi {}".format(self.person_name))

class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, company_name):
        Person.__init__(self, person_name=name)
        self.name = name
        self.company_name = company_name
    def greet_employee(self):
        print("Hi {} in {} company".format(self.name, self.company_name))

bob = Person("bob")
bob.greet_person()

john = Employee("john", "acme")
john.greet_person()
john.greet_employee()
```

**Output:**

```
Hi bob
Hi john
Hi john in acme company
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is the [`super`](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/inheritance.html#super) keyword. It calls the same method on the parent type. In this case, put `super(@name)` in `Employee#initialize` and it calls `Person#initialize` with `@name` as argument.

Alternatively, you can assign `@person_name = @name` manually in `Employee#initialize` instead of calling the super method to do that.

However, you might want to reconsider your object model. Having two pretty much identical instance variables doesn't seem like a good idea.
Maybe I'm missing something so, like that the values of these ivars can change independently of each other and the identical initialization is just so start things off.

EDIT: Added code sample.

```
class Employee < Person
  # alternative 1:
  def initialize(@name : String, @company_name : String)
    super(@name)
  end
  # alternative 2:
  def initialize(@name : String, @company_name : String)
    @person_name = @name
  end
end
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your question. I know my example is a little silly but it represents my problem. I have checked the `super` but I guess it doesn't do what I want. the super can invoke the method from parent class (so the methods should be have the same name). I want only the pass the value of `name` to `person_name`. Perhaps I didn't get your point. Probably an example can be helpful to understand your logic. :) I don't know if your are familiar with Python but the example in my question represents what I really want to do.

Comment: It's litterally just adding `super(@name)` to the method body. That's conceptually the same as `Person.__init__(self, person_name=name)`. I added an example for clarity.

Comment: Perfect! Your examples make clear your answer! Both of your solutions are working as charm! Big thanks! :)